# Excel 360 VBA to change pivot table filter

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to change the filter on a pivot table that was set up using the "Add this data to the Data Model" functionality using VBA which would read the selection of a list box containing the items to filter on. I started by recording a macro to see what would happen and was given this:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivottable1").PivotFields("[Range 1 1].[Quarter].[Quarter]").VisibleItemsList = _
    Array("[Range 1 1].[Quarter].&[1Q20]", "[Range 1 1].[Quarter].&[3Q20]")
```

My problem is to set up the array dynamically which could contain any number of items. I need to do something like the below but appending to the array each time which this doesn't do:

```
For x = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(x) = True Then
       myArray = Array("[Range 1 1].[Quarter].&[" & ListBox1.List(x) & "]")
    End If
Next x

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivottable1").PivotFields("[Range 1 1].[Quarter].[Quarter]").VisibleItemsList = myArray
```

I tested other ways which didn't work like using:

```
' This didn't work:
Set myArray = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
myArray.Add "[Range 1 1].[Quarter].&[1Q20]"

' This method didn't work either
Dim myArray(2) As Variant
myArray2(0) = "1Q20"
myArray2(1) = "2Q20"
```

I need to replace `Array("[Range 1 1].[Quarter].&[1Q20]", "[Range 1 1].[Quarter].&[3Q20]")` with something I can set up dynamically. Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: I feel you are not stating your real problem, if the data in the pivot you need to replace is static, it is not related to PivotTables, but is how to get a value from the listbox, and if the data in pivot is dynamic, i think you cannot. replace it.

Comment: All I need is to change a filter. I have arranged a list box outside of a dozen pivot tables and press a button to activate the macro and it changes all the pivot tables from many data sets without a problem. The problem is 2 exceptional pivot tables with "Add this data to the Data Model" which are handled differently. I need a way to construct the return from Array() dynamically based on the the listbox for these 2 pivots. The others are handled via a loop one at a time by adjusting visibility like this `pt.PivotFields("Quarter").PivotItems(ListBox1.List(x)).Visible = ListBox1.Selected(x)`

Comment: The macro is changing only the filter on each pivot table. My macro already works for regularly constructed pivot tables but not 2 which have the "Add this data to the Data Model" check box checked when creating the pivot table. These 2 pivot tables need to use the "distinct count of" feature so depend on this setup.

Comment: I just discovered that a method I said didn't work actually does, but I hadn't assigned the contents correctly - this worked:  `myArray2(0) = "[Range 1 1].[Quarter].&[1Q20]"`, `myArray2(1) = "[Range 1 1].[Quarter].&[2Q20]"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you need, but try something like this:

```
Dim myArray() As String,k as integer
ReDim myArray(ListBox1.ListCount-1)
k = -1
For x = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1

    If ListBox1.Selected(x) = True Then
    k = k + 1
       myArray(k) = "[Range 1 1].[Quarter].&[" & ListBox1.List(x) & "]"
    End If
Next x
ReDim Preserve myArray(k)
```

Comment: That technique worked. I had to make a small change when doing the actual assign to change the filter because `pt.PivotFields("[Range 1 1].[Quarter].[Quarter]").VisibleItemsList = myArray` didn't work for the second pivot table because I needed to say `pt.PivotFields("Range 1 2].......` so I set up a condition so it would be "1 1" for the first and "1 2" for the second. it would be nice to know how to work out it if it is "1 1" or "1 2" by looking at the pivot table itself and avoid the need for the condition but at least now the macro works. Thank you for your help.